# Typeerror: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined. (making a music bot)

Tags: node.js, promise, get, discord.js

I'm trying to make a music bot. This is the code that has an error.

```
const serverQueue = message.client.queue.get(message.guild.id);
```

Comment: We need the value in the message object to figure out the issue. But from the error message it seems that value for `queue` is coming as undefined.

Answer (score 1):

[Client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client).queue does not exist in discord.js.